# pear BBCodeParser2 couldn't parse WysiBB links

Tags: php, pear, bbcode

i used pear [BBCodeParser2](https://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser2) with [Wysibb](http://www.wysibb.com/) editor,it works good for most bbcodes like bold,italic,images....etc

the problem only in links,it can't parse urls in the topic,and when i look at db table, i found the url bbcode unchanged....
i checked all links and files included,and the problem still the same:

php:

```
       $config = parse_ini_file('HTML/BBCodeParser2.ini',true);
        $options = $config['HTML_BBCodeParser2'];
        $parser = new HTML_BBCodeParser2($options);
        $parser->setText($this->db->real_escape_string($_POST['t_body'])); 
        $parser->parse(); 
        $t_body= $parser->getParsed();
```

img from db:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution

the problem is that i should escape characters after parse() function
so the previous code will be:

```
 $config = parse_ini_file('HTML/BBCodeParser2.ini',true);
        $options = $config['HTML_BBCodeParser2'];
        $parser = new HTML_BBCodeParser2($options);
        $parser->setText($_POST['t_body']); 
        $parser->parse(); 
        $t_body= $this->db->real_escape_string($parser->getParsed());
```